# Batch: Replace all files with same filename

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I have a folder that looks like this:

```
folder-a
    folder-a-1
       file-2
    folder-a-2
       file-3
       file-4
    folder-a-3
       file-1
```

And I have a folder that looks like this:

```
folder-b
    file-1
    file-2
    file-3
    file-4
```

I'm looking for a batch (.bat) that replaces all files in folder-a with the files in folder-b based on filenames.

I hope this is not too much to ask but I'm sure someone is willing to give it a shot.

Comment: This is not how StackOverflow works! It is not a free code/script writing service but a resource for programmers to find answers to specific questions. So please learn [ask] here! Basically you have to try it on your own, and when stuck, return here, describe what your code is supposed to do and what it actually does, and share it! See also this article: [mcve]. As a starting point, take a look at the [`for /R` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html) and at the [`copy` command](http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html).

Comment: I've ran multiple tests but for some reason this seems to work:

Replace c:\folder-b\\*.* c:\folder-a /s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a .bat but .vbs, but is the function you are looking for. Then you should save as "samplename.vbs"

```
Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFolder = "C:\path\of\your\folder"
Set objFolder = objFS.GetFolder(strFolder)
For Each Folder In objFolder.SubFolders
    strFolderName = Folder.Name
    For i=1 To Len(strFolderName)
        if Mid(strFolderName,i,1) = " " Then
            strEndOfFirst = i
        End If
    Next
    strFirstName = Mid(strFolderName,1,strEndOfFirst)   
    strLastName = Mid(strFolderName,strEndOfFirst + 1)
    strNewName = strLastName & ", " & strFirstName
    Folder.Name=strNewName
Next
```